# What's wrong with the following false-proof that a subspace of a normal space is normal?

Tags: general-topology

The fact that a subspace of a normal topological space is normal is known to be wrong. 
 I'm trying to find the wrong step in the following proof: 
 
Let $X$ be a normal topological space and $Y$ be a subspace. Let $C_1, C_2$ be closed sets in $Y$. 
 So there exist $C_1', C_2'$ closed in $X$ such that $C_i = Y \cap C_i' $ for $i=1,2$. 
 Since $X$ is normal, there are open disjoint sets $U_1, U_2$ such that $C_i' \subset U_i$. 
 Thus $C_i=C_i' \cap Y \subset U_i \cap Y$. 
 So if we let $V_i = U_i \cap Y$, we get that $V_1, V_2$ are open in $Y$, disjoint, and satisfy $C_i \cap V_i$. 
 Therefore $Y$ is a normal topological space. 
 Where is the mistake?

Comment: Scrutinize your proof with a counterexample in hand.

Comment: $C_1,C_2$ disjoint does not imply $C'_1,C'_2$ disjoint.

Comment: I think that (C′i∩Y)⊂(Ui∩Y) would be clearer; I assume that's what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since $X$ is normal, there are open disjoint subsets $U_1, U_2$ such that $C_i' \subset U_i$

No, this only follows if you also know that $C_1' \cap C_2' = \varnothing$!

This is actually the source of two separate problems in your proof. Can you identify them?

Comment: Hard hour. I didn't even assume the original C1, C2 were disjoint apparently. Thanks, I'll accept the answer when the time limit expires

Comment: Yeah that's the second problem :) well spotted!